# How to insert an array in Postgresql with data from REST echo

Tags: arrays, postgresql, rest, go, request

I receive data into my echo rest api by post method. I have two arrays. I import pq library.
My structure is

```
type Lien struct {
    LinkID      int      `json: "linkID"`
    Linklabel   string   `json: "label"`
    Linkaddress string   `json: "address"`
    Langs       []string `json: "langs"`
    Cats        []int    `json: "cats"`
}
```

My post function is

```golang
func createLink(c echo.Context) error {
    l := new(Lien)
    if err := c.Bind(l); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    sqlStatement := "INSERT INTO link_test (label, address,langs, cats)VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)"
    res, err := db.Query(sqlStatement, l.Linklabel, l.Linkaddress, pq.Array(l.Langs), pq.Array(l.Cats))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(res)
        return c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, l)
    }
    return c.String(http.StatusOK, "ok")
}
```

It works for the first two fields but not for the arrays, I always get a null value.

Comment: Are you sure the two slice fields are populated by `c.Bind`? Try setting them manually at first just to see if the query works. Also you should not use `Query` when you don't expect to scan the returned `sql.Rows` object, use `Exec` instead. If you decide to stick with `Query` then at least make sure to call `Close` on the `sql.Rows` value, otherwise you'll run out of available connections.

Comment: Thank you MKopriva for your advices.

Comment: Well the problem is how convert [...] to '{"",""...}' ?

Comment: That should be handled by the values returned by [`pq.Array`](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#Array). For example passing it `l.Langs` which is a slice of strings will return [`*pq.StringArray`](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/master/array.go#L40-L41) which properly translates its contents into `{"", "", ...}` as you can see [here](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/master/array.go#L524-L545).

Comment: Thank you very much MKopriva for your consistent help, in fact I had l.langs instead of l.Langs as in Cats